# I found out a new employee is tapping fellow employees to look for job elsewhere

Tags: human-resources, employees

I got a new HR who has stayed for less than 3 months, I recently discovered he is telling my other employees to find job elsewhere. He infact is helping them update their Resumes and submitting to other companies as well.

What action should I take?

Comment: Do you have proof? Looks like a direct case for the company lawyer, no detours.

Comment: Sack him, do it now, If yu don't have the authority, take it to those that do. This is terrible for morale, you need to make an example.

Comment: @JoeStrazzere He is still with my company. I'm considering if just sacking is enough.

Comment: If you have proof, you should consider suing him for damages, and possibly the people behind him. If not, then sacking needs to suffice. But, whatever you do, do it fast!

Comment: ***If*** this is true, sacking is  the most you can do without getting your lawyers involved. It's probably the most you can do even with legal advice, really, unless you have explicit contract clauses which cover this case and you can point to damages sustained.

Comment: I love the irony here. People are expected to "poach" their friends and relatives from other companies for which they get a referral bonus, but put the boot on the other foot and all hell breaks loose.

Answer (score 5):

My first thought when I read your question was: "How good is this charlatan that he can convince his coworkers to take his advice after only three months?" Then I thought "How terrible must this job be, that his coworkers actually took his advice, at risk of losing their employment?"

People usually don't start looking for new jobs until the job they have is so terrible that they can't bear to plan their future around it, or they sense that their job is about to leave them (ie the company collapses, or lays off that department). But if employees can find any excuse to be loyal, they will take it - just look at all questions on here that are along the lines of "Through no fault of mine, my boss screwed me over completely, the company profits are in the negative, and I'm totally demoralized. . . . how can I save my job?"

I personally have been on the other side of your situation: the manager I was working for had become so cranky and unprofessional, and our salaries were so tiny, that a group of three people formed to help each other find other employment (not on paid time, of course).

I've also been in situations where I've offered to help former coworkers find new work because I thought their positions were terrible for them - and gotten rejected because, even though they knew it wasn't the best situation for them, they were just happy enough where they were.

If your employee is using company time/resources to do things unrelated to his job, then yes, you have a very good reason to fire him.

But if you've been keeping employees on for several years for no raises or chances for advancement, or telling them for a long time that you don't expect them to stay on and make a career at your company, or that they don't bring a lot of value to team, then you've been adding kindle to this fire all along, and continuing to do so will result in a bad reputation for your company.

All of this goes out the window, of course, if you can prove that there was some malicious intent behind him seeking employment with you in the first place, such as he was hired by another company specifically to sabotage your team - then you should call a lawyer.

And a final hypothesis - he might see the employees he's helping as 'dead weight' and is trying to do you (and himself) a favor by getting them off the payroll.

Comment: "People usually don't start looking for new jobs until the job they have is so terrible ..." - that sounds like an exaggeration. How about widening one's experience/horizon by switching into a somewhat different role/field within one's general realm of expertise? How about a chance to get from a good to an even better salary at the occasion of a job change? How about heeding the general advice to change jobs after a few years so the CV does not seem like one "got stuck" and couldn't land anywhere else? Calling the current job *terrible* seems too strong in such cases.

Comment: @O. R. Mapper How about "usually"?

Comment: @MaskedMan: From looking at my personal circle of acquaintances, I thought the situations I described are quite usual. Of course, that impression may not be generally valid across all fields and places.

Comment: @O. R. Mapper "How about heeding the general advice to change jobs after a few years so the CV does not seem like one "got stuck" and couldn't land anywhere else?" - that advice is very recent, and I sense that it might be coming from agency recruiters who only get paid when someone decides to switch jobs.

Comment: I think most employees in most fields like to think that they'll be at some place for about five years at least and get promoted, and people who've been in the workforce for a few decades are still very much afraid of being seen as a 'job hopper'. I still see advice from people of the baby boomer generation who insist that young employees "stick it out" in bad jobs, because they're still in the mindset of the old "put in your dues for thirty years and your get your pension" mentality.

Comment: As for the other reasons, keep in mind that savvy jobseekers will always paint a good story as to why they are leaving a job, because one cannot bad mouth an employer in a job interview. If they are switching roles, they have to be unhappy with the one that they have in some way, and even it's just salary, it's not just salary - it's the fact that the job seeker knows they can't get the salary they want at their workplace with less effort than going through the process of switching.

Comment: @MeganSullivan: "that advice is very recent" - depends on what you mean by that; I encountered it already some 15 years ago. The origin you suspect might be true, though. Of course, typical frequency and reasons for job changes vary considerably by culture and place, so your impressions may be very true for where you live. Still, I do believe that "If they are switching roles, they have to be unhappy with the one that they have in some way" is really an overly limited point of view, but a deeper discussion on this would probably lead off-topic for the question, maybe even for the site.

Comment: Keep in mind that in both these situations, that job seeker probably has some skills or experiences that make switching a lot easier. Most job seekers (even highly qualified job seekers) find the research, application, interviewing, and proving themselves in a new job to be challenging and time-consuming. From what I've seen in industries I've worked in, most people don't want to do it unless they really believe that they have to.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper The rule of "don't badmouth your employer" is so deeply etched in people's minds that most people don't disclose their real issues even to close acquaintances. I am not saying that is necessarily happening in your case, but generally, what people say does not necessarily match what they think (this applies to other situations as well). As far as job change goes, "if it isn't broken, don't fix it" seems to be the most commonly followed rule, especially when people have school-going kids and other dependencies.

Comment: @MaskedMan: 'The rule of "don't badmouth your employer" is so deeply etched in people's minds' - I never got the impression that rule had any relevance outside of job interviews. I have a hard time thinking of any acquaintance who has *never* badmouthed their employer towards me in one way or another (after all, that's a topic that people who know little about each other can usually connect over); it just doesn't happen a lot related to job changes (although this might depend a lot on the field etc.).